# GLSL Deferred Rendering can only output RGBA

Tags: opengl, glsl, deferred-rendering

I´m trying to do some shadows but the shader only outputs values if I use:

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
```

It doesnt work with vec3 or less.
You can check my texture properties here:

```
    shadowTextureProperties.setHasMipMap(false);
    shadowTextureProperties.setMagFilter(EnumTextureFilter.NEAREST);
    shadowTextureProperties.setMinFilter(EnumTextureFilter.NEAREST);
    shadowTextureProperties.setWrapS(EnumTextureWrap.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    shadowTextureProperties.setWrapT(EnumTextureWrap.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    shadowTextureProperties.setInternalColorFormat(EnumTextureColorFormat.RGB_32F); // 1st format value
    shadowTextureProperties.setSrcColorFormat(EnumTextureColorFormat.RGB); // 2nd format value
    shadowTextureProperties.setValueFormat(EnumValueFormat.FLOAT);
```

This is my shader fragment source with vec3 output and the format above, I'm getting a completely white screen. With vec4 I'm getting true depth values.

```
#version 400
precision highp float;
layout (location = 0) out vec3 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec3(gl_FragCoord.z);
}
```

**Results**

With vec3:
[image]

With vec4:
[image]

Comment: I have an idea what may be happening here and it has to do with blending. If you re-write the `vec3` version of this shader to `vec3 (gl_FragCoord.z * gl_FragCoord.z)`, does that change the output?

Comment: I tried it but no changes... With vec4 I`m getting an output.

Comment: Okay, with that out of the way... is there any reason in particular you want a 3-channel color texture to store your depth? You are duplicating the depth across 3 channels, each 32-bits. You could use a floating-point depth attachment and avoid the issue altogether. Anything that has color-renderable 32-bit floating-point texture support will also support `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`. At the very least, you could use a single-component color format. `GL_R32F`